# Django: Get the error messages of a form field

Tags: django

Is it possible to the error messages of a form field? I did some digging and the field has a property error_messages which is a dictionary but the values return:

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x2591d50>
```

So was wondering how I can get the error message from that? I am trying to add metadata to the data-validate attribute of the field's widget so I can use client side validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a translated string. To get the text, just use `unicode` on it:

```
unicode(error_message)
```

Comment: Thats the easiest way, but if all django is unicode already is there not a 'better' way of doing it? I've been looking for something but `unicode()` is the only solution I've found.